# Analyse trigonometrical function

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

Function is

$f(x)=\sin^3x+\cos^3x$

I'm confused when I need to solve $f(x)=0$ cause I got different values for the same x.

Also need help with

$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \sin^3x+\cos^3x$

Thanks

Comment: The limit doesn't exist. Hint: $a^3 + b^3 = 0 \iff a^3 = -b^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We have $\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x=0$ if and only if $\sin^3 x=-\cos^3 x$. This holds if and only if $\sin x=-\cos x$.

The equation $\sin x=-\cos x$ is equivalent to $\tan x=-1$. Note that this happens once in the second quadrant and once in the fourth quadrant. And if $x$ is a solution, so is $x+2n\pi$ for any integer $n$.

To show that the limit of $\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x$ as $x\to\infty$ does not exist, evaluate at numbers $n\pi$ where $n$ is even, and $n\pi$ where $n$ is odd.

Comment: Ok,thanks...I need to check one more thing about positive and negative values of x                                                  I've got that $f(x)>0 for {x \in (0,\frac{\pi},{2}) \cup (\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})$

Comment: OK. Your comment does not ask a specific question.

Comment: $f(x)> 0$ for $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}) \cup ( \frac{ \pi}{2}, \frac{3 \pi}{2})$ and $f(x)< 0$ for $x \in ( \frac{ \pi}{2}, \pi) \cup ( \frac{3 \pi}{2}, 2 \pi)$ is that correct?  Sorry for bad typing

Comment: It looks as if you are only going $0$ to $2\pi$. That's OK if it was specified, otherwise you have to add $2n\pi$. Note that $\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x$ will only change sign where $\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x=0$. So it is positive until $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, then negative until $\frac{7\pi}{4}$, then positive up to $2\pi$.